# In BDD can we replace [setup] with Given when we use gherkins syntax?

Tags: robotframework, bdd, keyword, gherkin, robotframework-ide

I use GHERKINS syntax:

```
GIVEN ..
WHEN ..
THEN ..
```

In my robot test cases 
My question is :
When i want to add [SETUP] + [TEARDOWN] how can i insert them?

Can GIVEN replace setup or i should include both ?

```
[SETUP]
GIVEN ..
WHEN .. 
THEN ..
[TEARDOWN]
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually we move the code to a single user defined keyword, and then call it from [SETUP] or [TEARDOWN].

Never tested but, it might be possible to write, in [SETUP]:

```
Run Keywords     GIVEN ..    AND    WHEN ..    AND    THEN ..
```

But then the Gherkin readability does not look so good.

Comment: But at that moment the test loose its structure (i mean the steps specially when there are many steps it becomes in only one line. I think with vertical declaration is more visible to the tester

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with replacing [SETUP] with Given word. [SETUP] is not mandatory, nor [TEARDOWN]